# can't load javascript because of missing mime type in asp.net core / iis express

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core

When using import in TypeScript, it looks for a path like "../File", without an extension. But when used on my site it can't read the file because of wrong mime type, but if I add the file extension it works.
So how can I add the correct mime type? Or is there any other fix?

The project is asp.net core.

> Loading module from “https://localhost:44361/script/Utility” was
>   blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“”).

```
import { ListenToEvent } from "./../Utility";
import { WebRequest, Request } from "./../WebRequestTS";

ListenToEvent("demo", async function (e) {
    console.log("click");

    var req: WebRequest = new WebRequest();
    var m = await req.Fetch(new Request("API", "Demo"));
});
```

**Startup.cs**:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings["nosniff"] = "X-Content-Type-Options";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\wwwroot\SCRIPT\"),
    RequestPath = "/SCRIPT",
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```